# I want to change which option that is selected in a combobox (<select>) with radiobuttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**html: simple select with a few options.**

```
<select id="link">
        <option>Small</option>
        <option>Medium</option>
        <option>Large</option>
        <option>XLarge</option>
</select>
```

**jquery: I have duplicated the select and then converted them into radiobuttons.**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#link').each(function(i, select){
    var $select = $(select);
    $select.find('option').each(function(j, option){
    var $option = $(option);
    // Create a radio:
    var $radio = $('<input type="radio" name="radios" value="all"/>');
    // Set name and value:
    $radio.attr('name', $select.attr('name')).attr('value', $option.val());
    // Set id
    $radio.attr('id', $option.val());
    // Set checked if the option was selected
    if ($option.attr('selected')) $radio.attr('checked', 'checked');
    // Insert radio before select box:
    $select.before($radio);
    // Insert a label:
    $select.before(
      $("<label>").attr('for', $option.val()).text($option.text())
    );
    });
    });
});
```

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T2Cc6/

Comment: Do you mind me asking, why? Also, what problem are you facing? Because if it's "just make it work", that's not really a question...

Comment: Why are you creating the radio buttons in javascript, instead of just putting them on the page?

Comment: @Zap7 I am helping in editing a webshop, on each page there is a <select> to determine the sizes, if i were to put them on the page that would take forever, instead of just easily adding a jquery file.

Comment: My question is how do i "control" the select box with the radio buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
$(':radio').click( function() {
    var size = $(this).val();
    $("select#link option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == size; 
    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2Cc6/1/)

Comment: Yes Thank You! Worked beutifully!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T2Cc6/2/)

```
$("#link").change(function(){
        $that = $(this)


        $("input[type=radio]").each(function(i, el){
            $("label[for='"+this.value+"']").css('background','#fff')

            if($that.val()==this.value){
                 $("label[for='"+this.value+"']").css('background','#e0e0e0')

            }
        })
    })
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
    $("label").css('background','#fff')
    $("label[for='"+this.value+"']").css('background','#e0e0e0')
    })
```